# How to start spring boot jar files one by one using windows batch file?

Tags: java, batch-file, spring-boot

I would like to start spring boot jar files one by one using windows batch file.
I have created a batch file like below:

```
start java -jar service1.jar --spring.profiles.active=local
start java -jar service2.jar --spring.profiles.active=local
```

When I ran this batch file, both jar files are running at once.
But I have to run service1.jar file first and once its up and running then I need to run service2.jar file.

Can anyone please help me with this or any other way ?

Comment: You could try adding `Start`'s `/W`ait option with your first `.jar` or removing the first `Start` altogether.

Comment: it would work with /wait if it was not a service but a process that finishes

Comment: You can use the SC command with the QUERY option to test if the service is started.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution would be starting first service in a new command process *(in background)*, wait for example two seconds and then start second service also in a new command process *(in background)* before exiting current command process.

```
@echo off
start "Service 1" /B java.exe -jar service1.jar --spring.profiles.active=local
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 /NOBREAK >nul
start "Service 2" /B java.exe -jar service2.jar --spring.profiles.active=local
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `start /?`
- `timeout /?`

Answer (score 0):

Using start in a batch file doesn't wait for the process - it is kind of like starting a new thread.

There is another function call (or start /wait ) but these will work if it wasn't services. The problem you have is that the services need to keep running (you can't wait for them to finish with start /wait).

So you need to implement some kind of condition and a check in your batch file which when true to start service 2. For example if that's a web service and has a get method that can be used to check if it is working - call that method and wait for the result before starting the second service.

You can do something like:

```
start java -jar service1.jar --spring.profiles.active=local

:isStarted

set ready=false // Here you implement some logic to check if the service is running

if %ready%=="false" goto isStarted

start java -jar service2.jar --spring.profiles.active=local
```

Another solution would be to make a separate java program that tests service1 and exits when it is up and running. If we call it "service1test" then your bat file will be:

```
start java -jar service1.jar --spring.profiles.active=local
service1test   - without using start so it can wait
start java -jar service2.jar --spring.profiles.active=local
```

Comment: 1. What's the `21` in your code? 2. I'd include a `timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK > nul` in the `:isStarted` loop in order to not heavily load the CPU (unless the `deletefile.vbs` script already contains a *sleep* command)...

Comment: a typo ;) sorry about that. It's more of a pseudo code